# Receiving different output for column SUMs in DB2

Tags: sql, sum, db2, aggregates

I have the following table in DB2:

| COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE | TYPE_NAME | COLUMN_SIZE | COLUMN_TEXT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DMPROD | -2 | CHAR () FOR BIT DATA | 35 | Product Code |
| DMPTYP | -2 | CHAR () FOR BIT DATA | 1 | Period Type |
| DMTYPE | -2 | CHAR () FOR BIT DATA | 6 | Type of Data |
| DMVL01 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 1 |
| DMVL02 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 2 |
| DMVL03 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 3 |
| DMVL04 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 4 |
| DMVL05 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 5 |
| DMVL06 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 6 |
| DMVL07 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 7 |
| DMVL08 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 8 |
| DMVL09 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 9 |
| DMVL10 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 10 |
| DMVL11 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 11 |
| DMVL12 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 12 |
| DMYEAR | 3 | DECIMAL | 4 | Fiscal Year |

Below query would return the sum of value periods for each Period Type, grouping them into Product Code

```
SELECT
    D.DMPROD,
    Sum(D.DMVL01 + D.DMVL02 + D.DMVL03 + D.DMVL04 + D.DMVL05 + D.DMVL06) AS Total
FROM
        DWM D
WHERE
        D.DMYEAR IN (2022)
    AND D.DMPTYP = 'M'
    AND D.DMTYPE IN ('RTNQTY','SLSQTY')
GROUP BY
        D.DMPROD
ORDER BY
    1;
```

Initial output:

| DMPROD | TOTAL |
| --- | --- |
| 11105 | 1145.75000 |
| 11350 | 625.37400 |
| 13135 | 2270.50000 |
| 13282 | -0.27500 |
| 13344 | -1.03300 |
| 15105 | 784 |

Then I changed this to work with a subquery thanks to feedback from other members. This is the preferred format:

```
SELECT
    D.DMPROD,
    (SLSQTY + RTNQTY) AS Total
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        D.DMPROD,
        Sum(CASE WHEN D.DMTYPE = 'RTNQTY' THEN Total END) AS RTNQTY,
        Sum(CASE WHEN D.DMTYPE = 'SLSQTY' THEN Total END) AS SLSQTY
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            D.*,
            (D.DMVL01 + D.DMVL02 + D.DMVL03 + D.DMVL04 + D.DMVL05 + D.DMVL06) AS Total
        FROM
            DWM AS D
    ) AS D
    WHERE
        D.DMYEAR IN (2022)
        AND D.DMPTYP = 'M'
    GROUP BY
        D.DMPROD
) AS D
ORDER BY 1;
```

but notice the sums are not the same (the initial output was correct):

| DMPROD | TOTAL |
| --- | --- |
| 11105 | 1145.75000 |
| 11350 | 625.37400 |
| 13135 | 2270.50000 |
| 13282 |  |
| 13344 |  |
| 15105 |  |

Where did I make the mistake with the sums?

Comment: Most probably SLSQTY or RTNQTY is null , try `coalesce(SLSQTY, 0) + coalesce(RTNQTY, 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These expressions:

```
    Sum(CASE WHEN D.DMTYPE = 'RTNQTY' THEN Total END) AS RTNQTY,
    Sum(CASE WHEN D.DMTYPE = 'SLSQTY' THEN Total END) AS SLSQTY
```

can return `NULL` if no rows for the `DMTYPE` are in the result.  That, in turn, affects this calculation:

```
(SLSQTY + RTNQTY) AS Total
```

The simplest solution is to add `ELSE 0`:

```
    Sum(CASE WHEN D.DMTYPE = 'RTNQTY' THEN Total ELSE 0 END) AS RTNQTY,
    Sum(CASE WHEN D.DMTYPE = 'SLSQTY' THEN Total ELSE 0 END) AS SLSQTY
```

This avoids the `NULL` value, so the total calculation does not turn into `NULL`.

Comment: I thought it might have been the NULLs, thank you, confirmed this works

Answer (score 0):

There may be a case when some `DMPROD` group doesn't contain rows with some `DMTYPE`. SUM for this type is NULL, and if such a value is used in the `+` operator, the result is NULL.
You may check the following example as is:

```
SELECT
  DMPROD
, RTNQTY
, SLSQTY
, RTNQTY + SLSQTY AS TOTAL_new 
, TOTAL_orig
, COALESCE (RTNQTY, 0) + COALESCE (SLSQTY, 0) AS TOTAL_mustbe 
FROM
(
SELECT
  DMPROD
, SUM (CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'RTNQTY' THEN Total END) AS RTNQTY
, SUM (CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'SLSQTY' THEN Total END) AS SLSQTY
, SUM (Total) AS TOTAL_orig
FROM 
(
VALUES
  (1, 'RTNQTY', 1)
, (1, 'SLSQTY', 1)
, (2, 'RTNQTY', 1)
) MY_TAB (DMPROD, DMTYPE, Total)
GROUP BY DMPROD
);
```

The result is:

| DMPROD | RTNQTY | SLSQTY | TOTAL_NEW | TOTAL_ORIG | TOTAL_MUSTBE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |  |  | 1 | 1 |